# JCalendarButton receive date

Tags: java, swing

How to receive a selected date using method actionPerformed?

Do you know other useful methods?

I cannot find proper method to receive selected date.

```
    _jCalendarButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {                   
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Object[] tab = _jCalendarButton.getSelectedObjects();                                   
        }
    });
```

Comment: Swing doesn't hve a JCalendarButton. Which API are you using? Where is its javadoc?

Comment: What kind of object is `_jCalendarButton`?

Comment: it's JCalendarButton, i found it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcalendarbutton/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a `PropertyChangeListener` rather than an `ActionListener` and read the new value from its `PropertyChangeEvent`

```
jCalendarButton.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
   public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
      if (evt.getNewValue() instanceof Date) {
         System.out.println(evt.getNewValue());
      } 
   }
});
```

Comment: The above code is the working code. All you have to do is register a `PropertyChangeListener` with your button

Answer (score 0):

The project is documented here: http://www.jbundle.org/jbundle/jcalendarbutton/quickstart.html. You must add a PropertyChangeListener on the button to be notified when the date changes. The ActionListener is only called when you press the button. Given that the project has no published javadoc, look at the [source code](https://github.com/jbundle/jcalendarbutton/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jbundle/util/jcalendarbutton/JCalendarButton.java) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select an date with GUI of Calendar you can use JXDatePicker (Component of SwingX). You will need an SwingX jar file to use it. 
Use the following code:

```
JXDatePicker datePicker = new JXDatePicker(System.currentTimeMillis());

datePicker.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   label.setText(datePicker.getDate().toString());
});
```

Comment: oops my mistake its SwingX. Sorry.